# Pin 1 in OPA237UA in SO package

Tags: pins, packages

I have built some circuit and it doesn't work.
**Can I ask if my interpretation of datasheet is correct?**

There is no hole, no proper dot on my package, but there is a symbol with 2 concentric circles and I interpreted that as pin 1 location.

This is how I I have done:

[image]

And this is image from [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa237.pdf):

[image]

And another one:

[image]

Comment: Did you buy it from reputable seller. Note that is a common practice to use an arbitrary chip with the same package and then print the marking of whatever chip that currently is good selling. There are posts of people that etched the chip and took snapshots with a microscope to prove they were deceived from those sellers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's correct.

Here are two useful ways of locating pin-1:

1. Hold the chip in a way that the top markings can be read. Pin-1 is located on the bottom-left. This also applies to QFP/LQFP and QFN packages.

[image]

2. There's almost always a 45° cut on one side of the package. Pin-1 is located on that side *(I marked the cuts with red rectangles in the following two images)*.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your interpretation is correct.

Of course, if you purchased the IC from other than an authorized distributor it may not be exactly what is claimed.