# TMUX1119 SC70 package first pin identification

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, multiplexer, pcb-assembly

I have a TMUX1119 with an SC70 package.

The datasheet says there is a dot near the first pin. The actual device that was received is shown below. I can see a line and below it is written 1DF.

Which is the first pin of this IC?

Is it the one which is left of the straight line?

[image]

Comment: [Link](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/559484/103420) Check the 1st method. The package in my answer is different but applies to your case as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in that the circled pin is number 1.

This is indicated by the horizontal bar on that end of the IC:

[image: Pin 1 Marked By End Bar]

Answer (score 1):

As per the datasheet of [TMUX1119](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tmux1119.pdf?ts=1627575975938&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F), the device marking code "1DF" indicates the SC-70 package.

[image]

The package drawing of SC-70 package is "DCK". The pin number 1 indication area is specified as in below pic.

[image]

Comment: I edited the question.Marked 1st pin in red.Could you please tell me if it is correct or not

Comment: I would say it is pin 1.