# TSOP - Identifying pin 1

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification, surface-mount

I have an SMD chip with 2 dimples at opposite corners. Am I correct in assuming that the smaller dimple identifies pin 1, and not the larger dimple opposite?

I'm sure I've heard in the past that if the text is upright then pin 1 should be at the bottom left. Correct?

[image]

Comment: See my answer [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/559480/pin-1-in-opa237ua-in-so-package/559484#559484).

Comment: @RohatKılıç Sounds like you are agreeing with my assumption.

Comment: Yes, I am. I should've said this in my comment above first then linked to the answer. Sorry.

Comment: @RohatKılıç Thank you. I will proceed with soldering - feel free to make your answer official and I will accept your answer.

Comment: Bottom left is the moulded pin 1 marker.  Top right is a mark left from the injection moulding process where the plastic entered the mould.  You'd be right to consider this confusing.